# how do i destructure an object only when key is present

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

how do I destructure an object only when key is present in the object or should I say  destructuring using conditionals

```
const arts = { a: 23, b: 3, c: 5}
const {a, d} = arts
console.log(d) 
// result produces an error on execution
```

I want a code where "d" won't be destructured if it's not a key available in the object.

Comment: You could assign a default value. It's seems weird to conditionally create a variable since presumable there is code that uses the variable. In the example above if `d` doesn't exist, what should happen with `console.log(d)`.

Comment: `d` will automatically be `undefined`. That behavior seems most reasonable.

Comment: Have you tried `const {a, d} = arts || {}` ?

Comment: let's say it's a login form a user might not fill all forms or something like that, and I need to destructure all keys since I'll be using each for specific purpose in my web app

Comment: yea I've tried that it gave me undefined

Comment: What else than `undefined` to you expect? The code above does not throw an error. If you are getting an error elsewhere then you have to update your logic to handle that value.

Comment: what is your expectation for d to log?

Comment: hmmm, I'm now confused... I don't want d as a variable at all since it doesn't exist, I want only a declared as a variable since it is a key in the arts object

Comment: @PedroJR, isn't that what your code is doing right now, it basically is saying that your d doesn't exist, it is undefined...

Comment: `const {a, d} = arts` creates two variables `a` and `d`. If you don't want `d` then don't include it. `const {a} = arts`. It's difficult to make suggestions if we don't really understand what you want to do.

Comment: If you don't want `d` to exist at all, use a conditional: `if (arts.hasOwnProperty("d")) { .. destructure and do whatever you want using a and d ... } else { ... don't destructure and do whatever else you want without d ... }`.

Comment: OK thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 3):

You could also try to use a default value for the properties like so:

```
const arts = { a: 23, b: 3, c: 5}


const {a = undefined, // The default could be 0 if it works for your use case.
       d = undefined,
       } = arts

console.log(d) // logs: 'undefined'
console.log(a) // logs: 23
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const arts = { a: 23, b: 3, c: 5}

if(arts.hasOwnProperty('a')) {
  const {a} = arts
  console.log(a)
  // do something with a
}
else {
  console.log('a was not found in arts');
}

if(arts.hasOwnProperty('d')) {
  const {d} = arts
  console.log(d)
  // do something with d
}
else {
  console.log('d was not found in arts');
}
```

Using `arts` as defined above will output:

```
23
d was not found in arts
```

The `hasOwnProperty()` method returns a boolean indicating whether the object has the specified property as its own property (as opposed to inheriting it).